# How can i check is specific property exist for control or not in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can i check background for Label here

```
if([Label has any color don't do anything]){  
    if (turn == Players.p1)
                    {
                        label.Background = Brushes.Red;
                        turn = Players.p2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label.Background = Brushes.Green;
                        turn = Players.p1;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: if (label.Background == null) ??

Comment: i tried that but didn't work...it has default "#00FFFFFF", so it gives me true always

Comment: "#00FFFFFF" is Transparent, so this should work  `if (label.Background == Brushes.Transparent)`

Comment: works like charm...thanx please mark your comment as asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for an empty `Background` by checking if its `null`, or perhaps it could be `Transparent`

So either

```
if (label.Background == null)
```

Or

```
if (label.Background == Brushes.Transparent)
```